# Joomla custom component adding browse button

Tags: joomla

I am developing a component in J! 2.5 and want to add a browse button on the backend so the user can pick a file they have previously uploaded. How would I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I have come up with, if someone can make it more robust and reusable, that would be great. I may do it myself later, but for now I have an impossible deadline.

loadDir.php:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['dir'])) {
        //Get array of valid extensions
        if(isset($_GET['ext'])) {
            if($_GET['ext'] == 'pdf') $validext = array("pdf");
            else $validext = array("jpg", "jpeg", "png", "gif");
        } else {
            $validext = array("pdf", "jpg", "jpeg", "png", "gif");
        }
        $root = dirname(dirname(dirname(getcwd()))) . "/";
        $directory = $root . $_GET['dir'];
        $files = scandir($directory);
        $thumb_count = 1;
        //make sure we haven't gone too high (should never be called)
        if(strpos($directory, 'images') == false) $directory = $root . "images";

        //TODO: sort array with dirs in front

        foreach($files as $file) {
            if ($file == '.') continue; //Remove current directory from loop
            //If in the images folder, don't let them go higher
            if ($file == '..' & $_GET['dir'] == 'images') continue;
            $path = $_GET['dir'];
            if($file == '..') {
                $path = dirname($path);
            } else {
                $path .= "/".$file;
            }
            if(is_dir($directory."/".$file)) {
                echo "<a href=\"#\" onClick=\"loadDir('".$_GET['div']."', '".$path."', '".$_GET['ext']."'); return false;\">[DIR]".$file."</a>".PHP_EOL;
            } else {
                //Check to see it's a valid extension
                $ext = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
                $num = rand(0,100);
                if(in_array($ext, $validext)) echo "<a href=\"#\" id=\"".$num."\" onClick=\"select(".$num.", '".$path."'); return false;\">[FILE]".$file."</a>".PHP_EOL;
            }
            if(($thumb_count % 5) == 0) echo "<br/>";
            $thumb_count++;
        }
    } else {
        echo "Error loading: Directory not available";
    }
?>
```

administrator/components/com_XXX/views/XXX/tmpl/form.php:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            selected_file = "";

            function select(id, file) {
                $('#' + id).css('background-color', 'red');
                selected_file = file;
            }

            function loadDir(div, path, ext) {
                $('#'+div+'Window').load('<?php echo JURI::root();?>administrator/components/com_lot/loadDir.php?div='+div+'&ext='+ext+'&dir='+path);
            }

            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#floorOpen').on("click", function(){
                    loadDir('floor', 'images', 'pdf');
                    $('#floorDialog').show();
                });

                $('#floorClose').on("click", function(){
                    $('#floorDialog').hide();
                    if(selected_file != "") $('#floor_plan').val(selected_file);
                    selected_file = "";
                });

                $('#floorCancel').on("click", function(){
                    $('#floorDialog').hide();
                    selected_file = "";
                });

                $('#mainOpen').on("click", function(){
                    loadDir('main', 'images', 'img');
                    $('#mainDialog').show();
                });

                $('#mainClose').on("click", function(){
                    $('#mainDialog').hide();
                    if(selected_file != "") $('#main_image').val(selected_file);
                    selected_file = "";
                });

                $('#mainCancel').on("click", function(){
                    $('#mainDialog').hide();
                    selected_file = "";
                });
            });
        </script>

......

<div id="floorDialog" style="position:absolute;display:none;width:400px;height:300px;border:1px solid #c0c0c0;background-color:#f0f0f0;top:800px;left:400px;">
        <div id="floorWindow" style="position:relative;width: 390px;height: 250px;margin: 4px;border: 1px solid #c0c0c0;">
        </div>
        <a href="#" onClick="return false;" id="floorCancel">Cancel</a><a href="#" onClick="return false;" id="floorClose">OK</a>
    </div>
    <div id="mainDialog" style="position:absolute;display:none;width:400px;height:300px;border:1px solid #c0c0c0;background-color:#f0f0f0;top:800px;left:400px;">
        <div id="mainWindow" style="position:relative;width: 390px;height: 250px;margin: 4px;border: 1px solid #c0c0c0;">
        </div>
        <a href="#" onClick="return false;" id="mainCancel">Cancel</a><a href="#" onClick="return false;" id="mainClose">OK</a>
    </div>

....

<tr>
            <td width="100" align="right" class="key">
                <label for="main_image">
                    <?php echo JText::_( 'Main Image' ); ?>:
                </label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input class="text_area" type="text" name="main_image" id="main_image" size="32" maxlength="250" value="<?php echo $this->lotdata->main_image;?>" /><a href="#" onClick="return false;" id="mainOpen">Browse</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="100" align="right" class="key">
                <label for="floor_plan">
                    <?php echo JText::_( 'Floor Plan' ); ?>:
                </label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input class="text_area" type="text" name="floor_plan" id="floor_plan" size="32" maxlength="250" value="<?php echo $this->lotdata->floor_plan;?>" /><a href="#" onClick="return false;" id="floorOpen">Browse</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

Basically I use AJAX to get a formatted list of files/directories. Then, using javascript we select the file we want and output the path on dialog close.

Comment: Trying to generate thumbnails but damn Joomla!'s structure is making it hard to do...

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the built in Joomla! form field **filelist** for this

`<field name="myfile" type="filelist" default="" label="Select a file" description="" directory="administrator" filter="" exclude="" stripext="" />`

**Full options are:**

The filelist form field type provides a drop down list of files from a specified directory. If the field has a saved value this is selected when the page is first loaded. If not, the default value (if any) is selected.

Params.filelist.jpg
By default, the first item on the list is '- Do not use -' (which is translatable) and is given the value '-1' and this is followed by '- Use default -' (also translatable) given the value '0'.

- type (mandatory) must be filelist.
- name (mandatory) is the unique name of the field.
- label (mandatory) (translatable) is the
  descriptive title of the field. directory (optional) is the
  filesystem path to the directory containing the files to be listed.
  If omitted the directory given by JPATH_ROOT is assumed.
- default (optional) is the default file name.
- description (optional)
  (translatable) is text that will be shown as a tooltip when the user
  moves the mouse over the drop-down box.
- filter (optional) is a
  regular expression string which is used to filter the list of files
  selected for inclusion in the drop-down list. If omitted, all files
  in the directory are included. The filter argument expression is
  applied before the exclude argument expression. For information on
  constructing regular expressions see Regular expressions in parameter
  arguments.
- exclude (optional) is a regular expression string which is
  used to exclude files from the list. The exclude argument expression
  is applied after the filter argument expression. For information on
  constructing regular expressions see Regular expressions in parameter
  arguments.
- stripext (optional) is a Boolean argument. If true then
  file name extensions will be stripped from the file names listed.
  Also note that the file name will be saved without the extension too.
- hide_none (optional) is a Boolean argument. If true, the '- Do not
  use -' item is omitted from the drop-down list.
- hide_default
  (optional) is a Boolean argument. If true, the '- Use default -' item
  is omitted from the drop-down list.

Here's where I got the list, I'm aware I'm not supposed to just link so I copied/pasted but I'll provide the original link in case the docs get updated.
https://docs.joomla.org/Filelist_form_field_type